# Update one column in mySQL table with CSV import

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

Thought this would be easy but after searching S/O I'm not finding a solution. Can you help? Any direction will be appreciated.

I have an existing 10-column table with column1 being `ID` (Primary) and column10 being `DATE`. I have a CSV file with 2 columns: ID (with IDs matching the table IDs) and DATE. I would like to import this CSV file to UPDATE (overwrite) the current info in the DATE column (currently 0000-00-00).

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: No way. CSV import (LOAD DATA INFILE) may load data into new rows (in temporary table) only.  You may ten use 2nd query and update existing values with loaded ones, and use 3rd query and delete loaded rows.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I was starting to suspect that with what I was reading but I thought I must be missing something.